# ‘Where did you be born’ versus ‘Where were you born?’

Tags: grammaticality, differences, questions, copular-verbs, do-support

I know this is the correct expression:

1. Where were you born?

At the same time, I wonder whether this alternative is grammatical:

2. Where did you be born?

Do you think sentence (2) is grammatical?

And does sentence (2) mean the same thing as sentence (3) means below?

3. Where were you born?

If (2) is not correct, or if (2) and (3) mean different things, please tell me why.

Comment: There are dialects in which "Where did you be born?" would be an acceptable question; I suspect that they are Welsh or English West Midland predominently. However they are not standard English of any sort and anyone saying it except as a joke would be in danger of being considered a poorly educated, and possibly stupid, yokel.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct.  Although a fluent English speaker would understand what you were trying to say,  the correct question is as you acknowledged, "Where were you born?".  The only thing that would be similar to what you asked would be "Where did your birth take place?"

Comment: I understood that that question I did was an incorrect expression.

Answer (score 0):

English doesn't have an active verb meaning 'be born' like the French 'naître'. You could say something like "Where did you come into the world?", but it would sound unnatural in normal conversation.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, BoldBen wrote:

> There are dialects in which "Where did you be born?" would be an acceptable question; I suspect that they are Welsh or English West Midland predominantly. However they are not standard English of any sort and anyone saying it except as a joke would be in danger of being considered a poorly educated, and possibly stupid, yokel.